# android unresolved class .MainActivity errors in manifest file

Tags: android, manifest

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="..."
        android:value=" ...."/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

android:name=".MainActivity" here problem. MainActivity unresolved class ?

I want to install my app on google play. But when loading apk it gave com.example error. So I changed the package name. Then I got this error in the manifest file. There are even red errors in the src section of the project.

Comment: Do you have a MainActivity class in the root of your poject?

Comment: Is this your complete code of Manifest.xml ??

Comment: No, I just threw some. to show the fault location @DIVYAPRAKASH

Comment: how?ı dont understand @cutiko

Comment: Do you have a java or kotlin file named MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check your java and the xml class of main activity. There must be an error in it.
Or 
You could show your class and xml here and describe the problem in detail

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MainActivity is in the root package of your project. 
Example:

If your package is `com.example.demo` then path of MainActivity should be `com.example.demo.MainActivity`

If your `MainActivity` path is `com.example.demo.activity.MainActivity`
then your Manifest entry should be like this

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
```

**EDIT**

If you changed your package name then you must use full path of your Activity, like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.demo.activity.MainActivity">
```

Comment: If you do what you say in the project in the androidTest in ExampleInstrumentedTest.java red show errors. I can't understand what it is @Rajat Mehra

Comment: @coding123 you are getting error in java class or in AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

PUT  MainActivity.java in Same package named com.example.test.MainActivity, it will resolved automatically.